# Regex Special Chars

Tags: php, regex

How would I go out regexing all '>' characters that are not part of html. 
For example;

```
<h1> 10 > 9 </h1>
```

Only the '>' and inside the h1 would be selected.

Comment: what would you do in case of  `<Hi> Man!! <this> just not gonna work bcuz I love angulars</bye!!>`

Comment: Ok well basically what I'm trying to do is escape special characters but not affect the html only the text of elements.

Comment: is it always valid html?

Answer (score -1):

I would just check for anything that is in between HTML tags.

`"\<.*\>.*\<.*\<.*\>"` That only picks out '<' characters isolated between the tags. Does that solve the whole problem or are you looking to take things from outside the tags?

Comment: Forgot to escape the '<' and '>' characters. My bad. It's working now http://regex101.com/r/bK6qG5/1